# Configring Nginx for rest api

Tags: php, .htaccess, rest, nginx

I have implemented Rest Api(Post) in apache server but when i moved it to nginx it not working. Here is configigration file i used in root directory called .htaccess.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php?rquest=$1 [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ api.php [QSA,NC,L]   
</IfModule>
```

All it does is if a request comes to ipaddess of my server like example.com/promocode_api/validate it sends request to api.php to process it.
But cant able to get configration needed in nginx to make it to work.

Here is my nginx code from etc/nginx/sites-enabled/defalut.

```
server {
    listen   80;


    root /purple_dev;
    index index.php index.html index.htm;

    server_name example.com;

   #     location / {
   #             try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
   #     }

    location /promocode_api {

    }

    error_page 404 /404.html;

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
          root /purple_dev;
    }
  # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on the php-fpm socket
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri =404;
            fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
            include fastcgi_params;

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably need somthing along the lines of:

```
location /promocode_api  {
    index       api.php;
    include     mime.types;
    try_files   $uri $uri/ api.php$is_args$args;
}
```

I fail to get the point why you have 3 different rules for the same target file though. I would deal with these in php.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i solved it.

This was neede to be added

```
location /promocode_api {
     rewrite ^/promocode_api/(.*)$ /promocode_api/api.php?rquest=$1;
    }
```